# python tkinter on screen keyboard with 2 entries

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem, i want to use an onscreen keyboard for 2 entries .

i have this code and thats exactly what i look for, but only for one entry. can please someone edit the code so i can use the same keyboard for both entries ?
i did try to do it my self but when i click the second entry and the keyboard pops up and i try to write something, all i write go to the first entry.

Thank you so much

```
import tkinter as tk
from functools import partial

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

num_run = 0
btn_funcid = 0


def click(btn):
    global num_run
    text = "%s" % btn
    if not text == "Del" and not text == "Close":
        e.insert(tk.END, text)
    if text == 'Del':
        e.delete(0, tk.END)
    if text == 'Close':
        boot.destroy()
        num_run = 0
        root.unbind('<Button-1>', btn_funcid)


def numpad():
    global num_run, boot
    boot = tk.Tk()
    boot['bg'] = 'green'
    lf = tk.LabelFrame(boot, text=" keypad ", bd=3)
    lf.pack(padx=15, pady=10)
    btn_list = [
        '7',  '8',  '9',
        '4',  '5',  '6',
        '1',  '2',  '3',
        '0',  'Del',  'Close']
    r = 1
    c = 0
    n = 0
    btn = list(range(len(btn_list)))
    for label in btn_list:
        cmd = partial(click, label)
        btn[n] = tk.Button(lf, text=label, width=10, height=5, command=cmd)
        btn[n].grid(row=r, column=c)
        n += 1
        c += 1
        if c == 3:
            c = 0
            r += 1


def close(event):
    global num_run, btn_funcid
    if num_run == 1:
        boot.destroy()
        num_run = 0
        root.unbind('<Button-1>', btn_funcid)


def run(event):
    global num_run, btn_funcid
    if num_run == 0:
        num_run = 1
        numpad()
        btn_funcid = root.bind('<Button-1>', close)

rand=tk.StringVar()
rand1=tk.StringVar()



e=tk.Entry(root, font='Verdana  8 bold',textvariable=rand, insertwidth=4, justify='right')
e.bind('<Button-1>', run)
e.place(x=10, y=10)
secondentry= tk.Entry(root, font='Verdana  8 bold',textvariable=rand1, insertwidth=4, justify='right')
secondentry.place(x=10, y=30)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Concerning your question "rewrite my code" - no.Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

You always call `e.insert` / `e.delete`.

You have to select the entry you want to write to and write to that one.

e.g.

- `selected_entry` as a global variable
- bind click event / extend click_event for *both entrys*
- inside the callback set `selected_entry` to the event callback source (caller)
- use `selected_entry.insert` / `selected_entry.delete`

Based on your code, the following 4 steps suffice:

### 1. define selected_entry

```
#[...]

# inside your global section (head)
# define the "selected_entry"

insert_entry = None

#[...]
```

### 2. adapt click event

```
# [...]

def click(btn):
    global num_run
    global insert_entry
    if insert_entry is None:
        return
    text = "%s" % btn
    if not text == "Del" and not text == "Close":
        insert_entry.insert(tk.END, text)
    if text == 'Del':
        insert_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
    if text == 'Close':
        boot.destroy()
        num_run = 0
        root.unbind('<Button-1>', btn_funcid)

# [...]
```

### 3. adapt run function to set insert_entry

```
# [...]

def run(event):
    global num_run, btn_funcid
    global insert_entry
    insert_entry = event.widget # use the caller to adapt it
    if num_run == 0:
        num_run = 1
        numpad()
        btn_funcid = root.bind('<Button-1>', close)

# [...]
```

### 4. fix bindings inside your "main"

```
# [...]

secondentry.bind('<Button-1>', run) # just like for the first one

# [...]
```